# Adding side menu to existing ionic app

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have this Ionic App which already has a lot of pages.
Now, requirements says that I need to add a page theat will "slide in" like this one:

```
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/
```

The app already has a footer like this:

```
<ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-assertive">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
        <i class = "icon ion-navicon-round" ng-click="go_to('settings')"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
        <i class = "icon ion-person-stalker" ng-click="go_to('social')"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
        <i class = "icon ion-map" ng-click="go_to('home')"></i>
    </div>
```

As you can see each element in the footer, on click, opens a new page.
But the most left icon has to open the page in a "slide" way.
So I guess I have to use ion-side-menus. Is that correct?

In that case I don't really understand how to implement this.
I created a new route like this:

```
.state('test', {
url: "/test",
controller: 'TestCtrl',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: "views/test.html"
})
```

Then inside test.html I put:

```
<ion-view>
<ion-side-menus>
    <!-- Left menu -->
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        ion-side-menu
    </ion-side-menu>

    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <!-- Right menu -->
    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        right
    </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
</ion-view>
```

Is all this correct? And how to trig the menu page? The one called test?
I tryed to change one of the footer elements and add this:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
```

But nothing happens when I click the button. Only an error message saying that:

```
Controller 'ionNavBar', required by directive 'ionNavButtons', can't be found!
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<ion-side-menus>
<ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark nav-title-slide-ios7">
     <ion-nav-back-button>
     </ion-nav-back-button>
     <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
     </ion-nav-buttons>
     <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
        </button>
     </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-side-menu side="left">
   ion-side-menu
</ion-side-menu>
<ion-side-menu side="right">
  right
</ion-side-menu>
```

Try this in test.html :) hope it will help you (y) In case check out this 
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/controller-ionnavbar-required-by-directive-ionnavbackbutton-cant-be-found-after-updating-to-beta-14/14925